# AVAssetReader problems in IOS5

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

I'm discovering problems with the AVAssetReader access to iPod library items in iOS5.   Since iOS5 is under NDA, here's a [link](https://devforums.apple.com/message/454113) to a thread I've started in the dev forums to discuss:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note to say this was in fact a bug, and it's now resolved in iOS5.